Compatibility of two atom spectra
I've measured in laboratory the wavelength of the emission lines of an unknown element.
I now have these values in a set (called x) along with their relative errors.
Now I need to compare my measurements to known values from a completely accurate source (stored in xtrue), that is, I have to check that the two spectra are the same.
How should I calculate this compatibility?
I am familiar with the concept of test hypothesis, so my first try was to define something similar to a chi2, so in python:
def chi2(x, xtrue, errs):
    if len(x) != len(xtrue) or len(xtrue) != len(errs): return -1
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum += abs(x[i] - xtrue[i]) / errs[i]

return sum

And that I suppose is, in some measure, a good indicator of the quality of my measurement, but I don't think i can normalize it in any meaningful way, much less finding the p-value through its distribution.
Am I wrong?
Is there any common way such matter are handled?
How should I proceed to give a solid statistical reason to why the two spectra are the same?
UPDATE:
A friend of mine suggested that i calculate the compatibility of every single line with a t-student test. This makes sense to me, but after that, how should I "merge" the many p-values into a single one? Do I just take the average?

Your chi2 function lacks the characteristic square: is that intentional or is it an oversight?

@whuber it's neither: I was going to construct a chi2-like function ad hoc, and then I just stopped because I had no idea how to proceed. With or without the square my problem remains

Although the general nature of your question is evident, it lacks sufficient detail.  What do you mean by "quality"? Do you need a formal statistical test or do you want to quantify the differences between the spectra?  What kinds of differences are possible (.e.g, sensor drift, counting statistics, correlated electronic noise, and so on)?  What kind of differences matter for you?  (Not all parts of spectra are of equal importance: usually you are focusing on a set of identifiable peaks.)

I'm doing this analysis in the context of an experiment for an exam in my university. What I need is a formal statistical test to prove (at 95% confidence, let's say) that the two atom spectra are coming from the same element. We only studied chi2 tests for functions, distributions and histograms and I was looking for a way to adapt it to my case. Also, I have no idea what you mean by "kinds of differences" and I'm not familiar with the examples you provided. If there's anything else unclear let me know and I'll do my best to explain myself better, thank you very much for your help

You might do well to research the list of examples I gave of differences: although it's incomplete, understanding these phenomena will help you understand the spectra better (and to appreciate there is no general solution to this problem, because it depends on the kind of spectrum, the sensor, and your objectives).
